# Why am I receiving an error when setting up a SSH Key for GitHub?

Tags: github, ssh-keys, decoding

I am trying to create a SSH Key for Github.
I keep receiving an error when I test my set up.

I have a macbook pro version 12.0.1
I have tried over and over again. I cant figure out the problem.
Please help

Step 1: Created a new SSH key
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "my email"
(this step worked perfectly)

Step 2: Added the SSH Key to the ssh-agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
(this also worked for me)

Step 3: Copied the SSH key to my clipboard
Pasted onto Github where it say add SSH keys

Step 4: Tested my set up and got an error...
/Users/teresarodriguez/.ssh/config: line 4: Bad configuration option: identifyfile
/Users/teresarodriguez/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong value in your ssh configuration, as the error states. You need to open /Users/teresarodriguez/.ssh/config and fix it

The error is likely that you have a typo. The option should be called `IdentityFile`, while you have `identifyfile` in there

Comment: Yea I did have a typo. lol Thank you!